# Using Kotlin Library in java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to use a GitHub library (MeowBottomNavigation)in Android Studio.But its written in kotlin and i cant use the listeners in it.
The only thing which is given is this

```
bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener {
}

bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener {
}
```

the suggestions shows to use

(Function1)

i am not sure as to how to implement this in java . Any help will be appreciated.

I am familiar with java but the library is written in Kotlin. Is there any way to use these listeners in java?

```
bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new 
Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model p1) {
            int i = p1.getId();
            switch (i){
                case 4:
                    Toast.makeText(UserMainActivity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case  1:
                    Toast.makeText(UserMainActivity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(UserMainActivity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Toast.makeText(UserMainActivity.this, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sounds very much alike https://stackoverflow.com/q/44301301/4636715 except `setOnClickListener` is mentioned there. May give you a clue.

Comment: I am not familiar with kotlin i want to implement it in java.The problem is the listener has no body and suggestions shows ( Function1 <?  super Model, Unit>  ) i am not sure how to use this in java.

Comment: This link might be helpful: [How to convert a kotlin source file to a java source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function0, Function1, Function2, ... FunctionN are higher-order functions in kotlin.

After converting to java, your click listeners become something like below.

```
// Set Menu Click Listener 
bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model p1) {
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });

// Set Menu Show listener
bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
        @Override
        public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model s) {
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: but how do i access the click event here. I tried using int i = p1.getId(); and then tried a toast to display the value.But its showing error  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4

Comment: Please see above I have updated the code please tell me where i am wrong.

Comment: also, you should add kotlin dependencies to your java app otherwise you will have a problem that says <cannot resolve 'Unit'>. you can do it by creating an extra activity with kotlin codebase and Android Studio will handle gradle changes automatically. You can delete the extra activity after that :-)

Answer (score 0):

something like This::

```
bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener( new IBottomNavigationListener(Model model)
{


} );
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol  IBottomNavigationListener & Model

Answer (score 0):

**if you are using fragments**

//1.-declare fragments globally in your activity

```
private HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
```

//2.- declare a method to switch between fragments

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.yourFragmentContainer,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

//3.- in the Set Menu Click/show Listener call the fragment to show

```
// Set Menu Click Listener







      bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model model) {
                    int i = model.getId();
                    switch (i){
                        case  1:
                            loadFragment(homeFragment);
                            break;
                            //...other cases
    
                    }
                    return Unit.INSTANCE;
                }
            });
        
        // Set Menu Show listener
        bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model model) {
                    int i = model.getId();
                    switch (i){
                        case  1:
                            loadFragment(homeFragment);
                            break;
                            //...other cases
                    }
                    return Unit.INSTANCE;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

use
implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'

for details watch
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiphbOtSyWY

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29930544)