# kotlin View.OnClickListener? was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get this toggle button to work - All I want to do is print in console "hello" but am getting this error

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but View.OnClickListener? was expected
```

package com.radiomedia.drn1

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        playButton.setOnClickListener(
           print("hello")
         )

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - How to achieve setOnClickListener in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301301/android-how-to-achieve-setonclicklistener-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `setOnClickListener()` method as any of the below options:

**Option 1:**

```
 playButton.setOnClickListener{
          print("hello")
    }
```

**Option 2:**

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        print("hello")
    }

})
```

**Option 3:**

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { view ->
    print("hello")
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use braces instead, like this:

```
playButton.setOnClickListener{
       print("hello")
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

either

```
    playButton.setOnClickListener {
       print("hello")
    }
```

or

```
 playButton.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })
```