# I get an error (unresolved reference) in Android Studio when trying to use "new View.OnClickListener"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-widget, onclicklistener

Im a beginner in Android Studio and have a school project where I have to create an login screen with password and username. When trying to follow some instructions online I get an error even though I have done the same as the instructor. Can you see what I have done wrong?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnYnF.png)

Comment: This is the video im trying to copy. And i get unresolved reference new when trying to do the same. See video from 19:00 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCrhddpsgKU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in Kotlin while the video you linked uses Java, so the error indicates that the `onClickListener` is not following Kotlin syntax properly.

The equivalent in Kotlin is:

```
logIn.setOnClickListener {
    // Do some work here
}
```

or

```
logIn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        // Do some work here
    }
})
```

Both will behave similarly. See alternative ways [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037634/11880323).

Answer (score 0):

// declare

```
private lateinit var logIn: Button
```

// cast

```
logIn = findViewById(R.id.logIn)
```

// execute the func you want

```
logIn.setOnClickListener {
    executeLogInApi()
}
```